# $n$ lines in a general position and the number of empty triangles

Tags: co.combinatorics, combinatorial-geometry

Question. Consider $n \geq 5$ lines in a general position (i.e. no two lines are parallel and no triple intersections are allowed) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $T(n)$ denote the maximal number of empty triangles (here empty triangle means that it does not contain other triangle). What would be best upper and lower bounds for $T(n)$? I know $(n-2) \leq T(n)$ holds, but I am hoping for a better lower bound. Is it true that $n \leq T(n)$? Also, is it possible to compute $T(n)$ it for small $n$ (where small means $6 \leq n \leq 10$)? I think $T(6) = 6$, but I am not able to show $6$ is an upper bound as well.

Comment: $T(n)\ge n$ is also true, taking the $n$ prolongations of the edges of a regular $n$-gone (this produces a triangle on each edge, if $n\ge 5$).

Comment: Assuming lines in general position, does the number of triangles depend on the relative position of the lines, or just on the number of lines?

Comment: Finding the best upper bound for T(n) will be no easy task; this is a well known open question in graph theory. A reference to your exact question came up in a 2011 Stanford Programming Contest. See part E (pdf p. 11/17) in http://cs.stanford.edu/group/acm/SLPC/problems.pdf.

Comment: @MP Great point! I think it does depend on the relative position of the lines, but I could be wrong. 

Comment: @gotmath: that's already clear with $n=5$. Five lines in generic position can produce 3, 4 or 5 triangles, according to their position.

Comment: Also, $T(n)\ge n$ is certainly not optimal. Just playing with $6,7,$ and $8$ lines I obtained partitions of the plane having respectively $7, 10,$ and $13$ triangular components. I wouldn't find it surprising  that $T(n)/n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Pietro Thanks for an update. Yes, I agree $T(n)/n \rightarrow \infty$. I was hoping to compute it for small $n$. 

Comment: (actually I had $T(8)\ge 14$)

Comment: $T(n)$ should grow at least quadratically in $n$.  Consider a configuration along the lines of all the lines of the form $x=k$, $y=k$ or $x+y=k+1/2$, where $k<n/6$.  All the lattice points $(x,y)$ with $|x|+|y|<n/6$ are involved in triangles with $(x,y+1/2), (x+1/2,y)$ and $(x,y-1/2), (x-1/2,y)$.  

Comment: That construction has both parallel lines and triple intersections, which are not allowed, but I think you can keep half of the triangles in a perturbation to general position while making a few more. A clearer starting point might be $3$ families of parallel lines which form the boundaries of part of an Archimedean tiling of the plane with triangle-hexagon-triangle-hexagon around each vertex. Any perturbation to general position keeps all of the triangles. 

Comment: I wondered if Tom Zaslavsky's region counting formula for hyperplane arrangements might help -- you will have exactly $n$ lines, each with Moebius function -1 and exactly ${n\choose 2}$ intersection points, each with Moebius function +1, hence exactly ${n-1\choose 2}$ bounded regions.  Is it possible to have a triangular region which has edges passing through it and yet does not properly contain any other triangular regions?  If not, then Zaslavsky's Theorem gives an upper bound of $T(n)\le {n-1\choose 2}$ (for whatever that is worth). 

Answer (score 4):

You can easily show that $3k$ lines can be arranged to have at least $\frac34 k^2$ triangles, which proves that asymptotically, $T(n) \ge n^2/12$.

The following picture shows the example for $k=4$ -- there are three groups of $k$ lines each, group 1 and group 2 forming a "squarish" $k\times k$ chessboard, which is being then intersected by the lines from group 3. They will produce $(k+1)+(k+1)+k+k+(k-1)+(k-1)+...$ triangles which comes to approximately $\frac34k^2$ triangles. And I am not even counting the ones that these groups will produce far away from the chessboard, inside their "own domain" so to speak.

[picture with 3 $k$ lines](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7t4T.jpg):

[image]

Comment: Actually, we can extend this argument (by carefully adding the triangles formed within groups 1, 2 and 3) and prove that $T(n) \ge n^2/9$

Answer (score 1):

The number of empty triangles $T(n)$ is lower bounded by the number of minimum area triangles $m(n)$ for which the asymptotic value is known to be $n^2/6$, see  [Triangle areas in line arrangements](https://arxiv.org/abs/1902.03166) by
Gábor Damásdi, Leonardo Martínez-Sandoval, Dániel T. Nagy, Zoltán Lóránt Nagy.